# Solve $u_x(x,y,z)=u(x,y,z)$ with $u(0,y,z)=y^2+z^2$. Is my work correct?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We have: $u_x(x,y,z)=u(x,y,z)$ with $u(0,y,z)=y^2+z^2$

We see that $\frac{du}{dx}=u$ thus $u=c_1e^{x}$. 

 Now, using the initial condition: $u(0,y,z)=y^2+z^2=c_1e^0=c_1$. Thus $u(x,y,z)=(y^2+z^2)e^x$. Do you agree with that ?

Comment: You are right. This is actually a simple ODE in the disguise of a PDE!.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your review. This question in fact appears in an old exam about PDEs, that's why I was unsure. Probably they wanted to confuse us.